# Where is my ruby installed when i install through RVM?

Tags: 12.04, ruby, rvm

right now i am running ruby 1.9 , which i installed using RVM .
I needed that to run my redmine 2.4.2 , since i had trouble using 1.8.

Now i need to configure my passenger mod to point to ruby 1.9 but i can't find it.

right now its configured like this :

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
PassengerRoot /usr
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
PassengerDefaultUser www-data
</ifModule>
```

and Since i get the same error as before, i guess it still uses my old 1.8 version.
running ubuntu precise 12.04

if you need additional information, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you execute

> rvm info

on your command line, you will get all the information about where certain things are. Your ruby executable you currently use will be shown under binaries.

You should also consult http://rvm.io/integration/passenger for more information how to integrate rvm and passenger.

Comment: great command, happy to know it now :)